# Save image locally from img tag with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, android-camera

I'm quite new to phonegap.

I'm using 3.1 version with camera feature.
I 've saved image file with camera.getPicture to the device storage, but now i have a new task:
after loading with the camera function, i manipulate the image dircetly with canvas tag, and so..

How can i save image locally from the img tag (that contains manipulated image), to the device storage?

Thanks in advance,
any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way, but you will need to search them, I can give you the rough idea.

Idea is base64 image string > send to native code > convert again to image > save it

You can put the image in `canvas` and convert the image into base64 encoded string.

```
function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
                var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image;
                img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
                img.onload = function(){
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
                    callback.call(this, dataURL);
                    // Clean up
                    canvas = null; 
                };
                img.src = url;
            }

convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function(base64Img){  //base64Img )
```

Sent this image string to native code. How! search in Google. There is a way called appView or you can write custom plugin.

Next convert the image string to image

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

if (base64ImageData != null) {
    fos = context.openFileOutput("imageName.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(base64ImageData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    fos.write(decodedString);

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    }

} catch (Exception e) {

} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        fos = null;
    }
}
```

[Convert a string in base64 to an image and save the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394122/convert-a-string-in-base64-to-an-image-and-save-the-image-file-as-png-to-the-fi)

and save it using native code.